# Android buttons use same Drawable for shape but use different colors

Tags: android, button, colors, drawable, reusability

In my application I am using lot of buttons. And all buttons must be in same shape but different in color. I wrote drawable for each button with same features but different solid android:color. This makes more 
than 20 drawable xml in my app. 
How can I use the same drawable for all buttons, but should be able to 
set different background color. 
I tried as below, but did not work.
1.  In attrs.xml

2. In drawable folder created buttonshape.xml for rectangle shape
3. In styles.xml 

           @drawable/buttonshape
          @color/mycolor
4. In Colors.xml
   #000000

And finally in my activity xml, for the button I set the theme as

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnTest" 
android:theme="@style/TestTheme"   android:text="Test" />
```

This did not work for me. Could anyone of you please help me to sort this out? I am a new to android     development. I am not able to figure out where I am    going wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks,
Roger

Comment: get this drawable background on run time and change the background color.

Answer (score 4):

use this: GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)view.getBackground().getCurrent(); bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);

where ever you want to set different color of any view, just use this code.

.getCurrent gives the selected drawable layerlist

use this it will not throw java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable exception.

it works perfectly for me.